# renderJson without template

Tags: java, playframework

I have controller with

```
render(messages);
```

And i have route

```
GET     /                                       Application.index
```

I want to implement some rest features, and add this route

```
GET     /api/index                              Application.index(format:'json')
```

I have template not found exception. How can i say to play use renderJSON() when format is json without any code changes?

Answer (score 0):

As you use the render() method, Play! will search a template file with the name of the action (detail on Play! website : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/controllers#template).

You have to use renderJSON(params...), it will bypass the default template!

Answer (score 0):

Your use case doesn't really make sense.  In the standard render() call, you are likely passing some pojos to the template to use (or none at all), this is a varargs method.  In the renderJSON() call you always need to pass an object which can be serialized to json by the Gson library, or a string with is already in json.

Add a new method to your Application class that handles json responses:

```
# normal index page
GET     /             Application.index
# api request
GET     /api/index    Application.indexJson
```